# How to decrease the size between menu items in Wordpress Dali theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on the following site: https://essentialsdirectonline.com/

I would like to line up all the menu items on one line together instead of seeing "More" dropdown menu.

I already minimized the size of the text using `CSS Style` section for theme customization.

I believe that I need to decrease the space between all the menu items.

If that's the case, how can I do it. If it's not the way to go, do you have any suggestions on what I need to do?

Thank you